# javafx fxml: page language not specified - JavaScript seems not to be supported

Tags: javascript, javafx, fxml

The FXMLLoader does not recognize the `<?language javascript?>` directive when trying to process an fxml script (see below). The error message is "Page language not specified". My fxml is like follows (actual code ommitted for brevity):

```
<?language javascript?>

<!-- differnet includes -->
...

<!-- actual fxml -->
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:controller="com.xxx.xxx.MainViewController"
           prefWidth="1200">

...

    <!-- somewhere in the middle of the fxml code -->
    <fx:script>
        function clearTool1() {
            tool1.setValue(null);
        }
    </fx:script>

...

<StackPane/>
```

I have investigated a bit and found out that the `ScriptEngineManager` class of javafx actually does not see any script engines. In particular, in its `getEngineByName` method, the collection of `ScriptEngineFactory` is empty, so it does not find any javascript engine and throws the exception later on. I will not go into details on this since the goal is not to debug javafx source code but I thought it could be useful as a hint.

Do you have any idea why the scripting language directive is not recognized although the fxml and everything else is written correctly?

Comment: What is your JDK version? Nashorn was removed from the platform in JDK 15, I think.

Comment: @Pointy yes, in build and run config I have java 15 SDK of '${my-module}' module. this means no fxml scripting support?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: https://golb.hplar.ch/2020/04/java-javascript-engine.html. You may be the first person to try to use javascript in FXML since Java 15... This is not very common, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @James_D thank you, I am going to examine this in a while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, you have to include the scripting engine implementation into your pom...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groudId>
    <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to @Pointy and @James_D for giving a hint regarding that.